# Replace NaN with the value above (for matching IDs) - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan

I have a matrix with Col1 IDs and Col2 Values.

```
mat = [ ...
      1000 3
      1000 4
      1000 nan
      1000 nan
      1000 5

      2222 1
      2222 2
      2222 nan

      3333 nan

      4444 1 ] ;
```

I need to replace `nan` with the value in the row above it, but subject to the condition: row above should have the same ID.

Answer:

```
mat = [ ...
      1000 3
      1000 4
      1000 4
      1000 4
      1000 5

      2222 1
      2222 2
      2222 2

      3333 nan

      4444 1 ] ;
```

Can you suggest a vectorized approach?

Comment: I don't think this problem vectorizes well because of the need to find the first non-NaN value if there are consecutive NaNs with the same ID.

Comment: Simple loops are very fast with Matlab's JIT.  Does a loop not meet your needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code won't handle consecutive NaNs with the same ID.

```
inds = find([mat(2:end,1)==mat(1:end-1,1)] & isnan(mat(2:end,2)))
mat(inds+1,2) = mat(inds,2)
```

Running it twice on the sample data completes the task.

Comment: The first condition can be written simply `diff(mat(:,1)) == 0`.  Then just loop while `numel(inds) > 0`.

Comment: @Ben could you please explain 'the first condition?'.... is that equivalent to replacing [mat(2:end,1)==mat(1:end-1,1)] ?